# What persistence problems are solved with CQRS?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, read-write

I've read a few posts relating to this, but i still can't quite grasp how it all works.

Let's say for example i was building a site like Stack Overflow, with two pages => one listing all the questions, another where you ask/edit a question. A simple, CRUD-based web application.

If i used CQRS, i would have a seperate system for the read/writes, seperate DB's, etc..great.

Now, my issue comes to how to update the *read* state (which is, after all in a DB of it's own).

Flow i assume is something like this:

`WebApp => User submits question
WebApp => System raises 'Write' event
WriteSystem => 'Write' event is picked up and saves to 'WriteDb'
WriteSystem => 'UpdateState' event raised
ReadSystem => 'UpdateState' event is picked up
ReadSystem => System updates it's own state ('ReadDb')
WebApp => Index page reads data from 'Read' system`

Assuming this is correct, how is this significantly different to a CRUD system read/writing from same DB? Putting aside CQRS advantages like seperate read/write *system* scaling, rebuilding state, seperation of domain boundaries etc, what problems are **solved** from a *persistence* standpoint? Lock contention avoided?

I could achieve a similar advantage by either using queues to achieve single-threaded saves in a multi-threaded web app, or simply replicate data between a read/write DB, could i not?

Basically, I'm just trying to understand if i was building a CRUD-based web application, why i would care about CQRS, from a pragmatic standpoint.

Thanks!

Comment: "Assuming this is correct" - but it is not quite correct. May I edit your question to correctly model according to CQRS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Assuming this is correct, how is this significantly different to a CRUD system read/writing from same DB? Putting aside CQRS advantages like seperate read/write system scaling, rebuilding state, seperation of domain boundaries etc, what problems are solved from a persistence standpoint? Lock contention avoided?

The problem here is:

> "Putting aside CQRS advantages …"

If you take away its advantages, it's a little bit difficult to argue what problems it solves ;-)

The key in understanding CQRS is that you separate reading data from writing data. This way you can optimize the databases as needed: Your write database is highly normalized, and hence you can easily ensure consistency. Your read database in contrast is denormalized, which makes your reads extremely simple and fast: They all become `SELECT * FROM …` effectively.

Under the assumption that a website as StackOverflow is way more read from than written to, this makes a lot of sense, as it allows you to optimize the system for fast responses and a great user experience, without sacrificing consistency at the same time.

Additionally, if combined with event-sourcing, this approach has other benefits, but for CQRS alone, that's it.

*Shameless plug*: My team and I have created a comprehensive introduction to CQRS, DDD and event-sourcing, maybe this helps to improve understanding as well. See [this website](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.0.1/downloads/brochure/) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (+1).The reason for the 'putting aside advantages' sentence was I am trying to understand _persistence_ benefits, not other benefits. The normalised/denormalized point is a good one. This may be nitpicking, but what about lock contention? Something still needs to _write_ to the denormalized read store after it needs to update state, right? Couldn't I get the same result with something like SQL server replication, which denormalizes the data on the way out?

Comment: Of course. Nobody says that it *need* to be two databases, you could also use one, and simply two tables. The point here is to conceptually separate reading from writing, not technically. But you get all the other benefits (scalability, …) only if you also technically separate them.

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point would be to review [Greg Young's 2010 essay](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/), where he tries to clarify the limited scope of the CQRS pattern.

> CQRS is simply the creation of two objects where there was previously only one....  This separation however enables us to do many interesting things architecturally, the largest is that it forces a break of the mental retardation that because the two use the same data they should also use the same data model.

The idea of multiple data models is key, because you can now begin to consider using data models that are fit for purpose, rather than trying to tune a single data model to every case that you need to support.

Once we have the idea that these two objects are logically separate, we can start to consider whether they are physically separate.  And that opens up a world of interesting trade offs.

> what problems are solved from a persistence standpoint?

The opportunity to choose fit for purpose storage.  Instead of supporting all of your use cases in your single read/write persistence store, you pull documents out of the key value store, and run graph queries out of the graph database, and full text search out of the document store, events out of the event stream....

Or not!  if the cost benefit analysis tells you the work won't pay off, you have the option of serving all of your cases from a single store.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your applications needs.

A good overview and links to more resources here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs

When to use this pattern:

Use this pattern in the following situations:

> Collaborative domains where multiple operations are performed in parallel on the same data. CQRS allows you to define commands with
>   enough granularity to minimize merge conflicts at the domain level
>   (any conflicts that do arise can be merged by the command), even when
>   updating what appears to be the same type of data.
>
> Task-based user interfaces where users are guided through a complex process as a series of steps or with complex domain models.
>   Also, useful for teams already familiar with domain-driven design
>   (DDD) techniques. The write model has a full command-processing stack
>   with business logic, input validation, and business validation to
>   ensure that everything is always consistent for each of the aggregates
>   (each cluster of associated objects treated as a unit for data
>   changes) in the write model. The read model has no business logic or
>   validation stack and just returns a DTO for use in a view model. The
>   read model is eventually consistent with the write model.
>
> Scenarios where performance of data reads must be fine tuned separately from performance of data writes, especially when the
>   read/write ratio is very high, and when horizontal scaling is
>   required. For example, in many systems the number of read operations
>   is many times greater that the number of write operations. To
>   accommodate this, consider scaling out the read model, but running the
>   write model on only one or a few instances. A small number of write
>   model instances also helps to minimize the occurrence of merge
>   conflicts.
>
> Scenarios where one team of developers can focus on the complex domain model that is part of the write model, and another team can
>   focus on the read model and the user interfaces.
>
> Scenarios where the system is expected to evolve over time and might contain multiple versions of the model, or where business rules
>   change regularly.
>
> Integration with other systems, especially in combination with event sourcing, where the temporal failure of one subsystem shouldn't
>   affect the availability of the others.

This pattern isn't recommended in the following situations:

> Where the domain or the business rules are simple.
>
> Where a simple CRUD-style user interface and the related data access operations are sufficient.
>
> For implementation across the whole system. There are specific components of an overall data management scenario where CQRS can be
>   useful, but it can add considerable and unnecessary complexity when it
>   isn't required.